# BASH: recursively search through a file system and rename files

Tags: regex, bash, recursion, find, file-rename

I am trying to search through the file system and rename files if they are `*-xxx.png` to '*.png' or `*-xxx.jpg` to `*.jpg` (removing the `xxx` value), and to `*.png.bak` or `*.jpg.bak` if they do not have `*-xxx.ext`.
I am already using a script to execute a command on each file

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find . -name "*.png")
do
    cp $file $file.bak
    pngquant -vf $file 
    echo  "mv $? ${file} "  
done
echo $?
```

I need this script to also be able to back up the old file and rename the new file to the old filename. the new file is the old file name with `-xxx` appended to the filename before the extension.

Comment: Where is the part of your script that removes `xxx`?

Comment: The output of pngquant -vf $file should be the filename with -xxx and the nextline would hopefully have saved it as the original filename

Comment: To get the output of a command into a variable you use `var=$(command)`. `$?` contains the exit status of the command, not the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '\(.*\.png\)\|\(.*\.jpg\)' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' img; do
    [[ ${img} =~ - ]] && mv ${img} ${img%-*}.jpg || mv ${img} ${img}.bak
done
```

This, of course, assuming you want to change `png` extensions to `jpg`, as I concluded from your question. If you don't wish to alter, for instance, `file-xxx.png` to `file.jpg` then use the following code:

```
for ext in jpg png; do
    find . -name *${ext} -print0 | while read -d $'\0' img; do
        [[ ${img} =~ - ]] && mv ${img} ${img%-*}.${ext} || mv ${img} ${img}.bak
    done
done
```

Comment: no Im not changing .png to .jpg, Im optimizing .png and .jpg files which is saving the new optimized files with an additional -xxx string in the name of the new file.  so Ill have file1.jpg, file1-xxx.jpg, and file2.png and file-xxx.png, where I need file1.jpg and file2.png to become file1.jpg.bak and file2.png.bak, thus leaving room for file1-xxx.jpg to become file1.jpg and file2-xxx room to become file2.png

Comment: Then change this in your post: " rename files if they are `*-xxx.png` or `*-xxx.jpg` to `*.jpg`". The second block of code should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, to take all '*.jpg' except those named `*-xxx.jpg` and then add `.bak` to the end of their name:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' ! -name '*-xxx.jpg' -exec mv {} {}.bak \;
```

Second, to do the same for png files:

```
find . -name '*.png' ! -name '*-xxx.png' -exec mv {} {}.bak \;
```

Third, to rename all the `-xxx.jpg` and `-xxx.png` files to remove `-xxx` from their names:

```
find . \( -name '*-xxx.jpg' -o -name '*-xxx.png' \) -exec rename 's/-xxx.(jpg|png)/.$1/' {} +
```

This last command *requires* the often convenient `rename` utility that, on debian-like systems, is installed as part of the `perl` package.  It will not work with the different *and incompatible* `rename` utility that is installed with the `util-linux` package.